# Piston that produces equal amounts of swing in a lever?

Tags: mechanisms, mathematics, geometry

I am attempting to figure out an equation I've found for designing part of Walschaerts Valve Gear. The specific implementation isn't relevant here, because it's the math I'm after, but this is the idea. I have removed non-relevant parts of the gear.
[image]

The *eccentric rod* is driven by the wheel on the right, and pushes on the *expansion link,* which swings back and forth on a trunnion. As you can see, the expansion link is mostly curved, but it has a little foot at the base. The idea behind this foot is to create geometry where by the angle of swing from each of the dead centers to mid-piston travel is the same. (There are inherently going to be some small angularity errors here, for example the various mid-points and dead centers won't be precisely 90 degrees apart.)

Here are the equations given in D.L. Ashton's "Design Procedures for Walschaerts and Stephenson's Valve Gears," though the equations themselves are credited to A. Gettings.
[image]
*I have highlighted the relevant assumed-known variables in green. The yellow-highlighted angle $γ$ (gamma) can safely be ignored/assumed to equal 0 for the purposes of this question. The desired unknown variables are in red.*

[image]
The first equation for finding $θ$ (theta) is obvious enough. My question is the following: how was the equation for finding $β$ (beta) derived from this geometry?

Comment: Have you checked out the scotch yoke?

Comment: That would undoubtedly produce better results because you lose the angularity errors, but I suspect the reason it was never implemented for walschaerts valve gear was that it was either too weak or resulted in too much mechanical wear given the forces involved. Neat though.